# Printing a map with multiple objects using toString()

Tags: java, tostring

I am making a pacman simulator in java without interface, only using console printing and I came across a problem while printing.
So, I have an object pacman that has his coordinates x and y, I have a grid with walls and fruti which is the matrix tile[][]. 
While I was only printing the pacman and the grid, everything was ok. 
This is the toString() I used:

```
public String toString() {
        String s = "";
        for(int i=0;i<WIDTH;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<HEIGHT;j++) {
                if(pacman.getX() == i && pacman.getY() == j) {
                    s = s + pacman;
                } 
                else {  
                    s = s+tile[i][j];   
                }


            }
            s=s+"\n";
        }
        return s;
    }
```

this is the output:

```
####################
#<~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
####################
```

Now, I created an array list of ghosts, and I have some issues when I want to print the ghosts, the pacman and the grid.
I want the character representing the ghosts to be above the character of the grid, just like I did with the pacman.
I just can't figure out the best way to print the ghosts above the tiles.
I am using the foreach loop like this:

```
for(Ghost g : ghosts) {
  if(g.getX() == i && g.getY() == j) {
        s = s + g;
  }
}
```

Usually I get the print in the console like this:

```
####################
#<~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~3~~~~~2~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~1~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
####################
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You have to use an `else` like you did for the pacman.

Comment: @markspace yes, but I can't find the right place to put it. should I do an else if.. I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to get rid of the '~'s in some way. you can do this by instead using a 2d char array instead of a string, like this:

```
char[][] map = new char[width][height];
```

then you can just edit every 'pixel' like so:

```
map[y][x] = g;
```

EDIT: you would then draw the screen by looping through all of the chars, writing them into a string and placing a \n after each row.

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be a little trickier than I thought, but I think you can conditionally `continue` the row processing (the inner `j` loop) and it works out.  You do have to put the ghosts in your `else` block though.  Untested:

```
        ROW: 
        for(int j=0;j<HEIGHT;j++) {                 
            if(pacman.getX() == i && pacman.getY() == j) {
                s = s + pacman;
            } 
            else { 
                for(Ghost g : ghosts) {
                  if(g.getX() == i && g.getY() == j) {
                    s = s + g;
                    continue ROW;
                  } 
                 s = s+tile[i][j];   
               }
            }
```